# Sublime Text Editor 3: "Uncaught ReferenceError: sjs is not defined"

Tags: javascript, game-development

I'm new to Sublime Text Editor, and this if my first experience with writing script. I'm hoping to make some simple custom games to use in my classroom with 6th graders while also being able to instruct them how to make such games. I'm attempting to follow along with the following tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qspa4rKazU

Here is my own code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Coding Example</title>
<script>
function start(){
sjs.open();

    var background = new sjs.Image("Images/street.png");
    background.setSize(800, 500);

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
<h1> Exampleg </h1>

<div id="target" style="margin:auto;background:grey;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error message that I receive when I attempt to open in browser:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: sjs is not defined
    at start (index.html:7)
    at onload (index.html:15)"

This error message doesn't appear on the tutorial, even though my code is written the same way. I believe this is why I can't get the background image to display.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to define sjs

Answer (score 0):

If you look at line 5 of the video they have following:

```
<script src="https://simplycodingcourses.com/files/simplyjs.simply.js"></script>
```

This is a content delivery network address that has the sjs javascript file.

You need to include that in to your code you pasted above to get this to work.

Comment: Thank you. That content delivery network address fails to load. I assume I'll need to create/pay for my own?